# Why is this generator expression function slower than the loop version?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, generator, generator-expression

I have been operating under the theory that generator expressions tend to be more efficient than normal loops. But then I ran into the following example: write a function which given a number, `N`, and some factors, `ps`, returns the sum of all the numbers under `N` that are a multiple of at least one factor.

Here is a loop version and a shorter generator expression version:

```
def loops(N, ps):
    total_sum = 0 
    for i in xrange(N):
        for p in ps: 
            if i%p == 0:
                total_sum += i
                break
    return total_sum

def genexp(N, ps):
    return sum(i for i in xrange(N)
               if any(i%p == 0 for p in ps))
```

I'd expect the two to perform roughly equal, with maybe the comprehension version a little faster, but what I didn't expect was this:

```
for func in ('loops', 'genexp'):
    print func, timeit.timeit('%s(100000, [3,5,7])' % func, 
                              number=100, 
                              setup='from __main__ import %s' % func)


loops 2.82878184319
genexp 10.1663100719
```

4x slower isn't even close! Why? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You have *generator expressions*, not list comprehensions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! Clearly I'm not a python guy :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all: generator expressions are *memory* efficient, not necessarily speed efficient.

Your compact `genexp()` version is slower for two reasons:

- Generator expressions are implemented using a new scope (like a new function). You are producing *N* new scopes, one for for each `any()` test. Creating a new scope and tearing it down again is relatively expensive, certainly when done in a loop and then compared with code that doesn't do this.
- The `sum()` and `any()` names are additional globals to be looked up. In the case of `any()`, that's an additional *N* global lookups per test. Globals must be looked up in a dictionary, versus locals which are looked up by index in a C-array (which is very fast).

The latter is but a small component, most of the cost lies in creating and destroying frames (scopes); if you create a version where `_any` and `_sum` are locals to the function you get but a small improvement in performance:

```
>>> def genexp_locals(N, ps, _any=any, _sum=sum):
...     return _sum(i for i in xrange(N)
...                if _any(i%p == 0 for p in ps))
... 
>>> for func in ('loops', 'genexp', 'genexp_locals'):
...     print func, timeit.timeit('%s(100000, [3,5,7])' % func, 
...                               number=100, 
...                               setup='from __main__ import %s' % func)
... 
loops 2.00835800171
genexp 6.45241594315
genexp_locals 6.23843789101
```

I didn't create a local for `xrange` to keep that aspect the same. Technically speaking, the `_any` name is looked up as a closure, not a local, by the generator expression code object, which are not as slow as global lookups but not quite as speedy as a local lookup either.

Comment: I think "N new scopes for each any() test" should be "N new scopes, one for each any() test". And I think there's another cost that you don't mention, the cost of the back and forth between the generator objects and their consumers.

Comment: @Manuel: that overhead is somewhat negligible compared to all the other overheads. Thanks for the suggestion about the wording, I've folded that in.

Comment: Do you mean it's negligible in general, or just in this particular case (as these generators here barely produce anything)?

Comment: @Manuel: in this specific case.