# Python built-in functions such as any

Tags: python

I wrote a function to know whether a number is prime in Python (using Python 3.8.1 in this case). See `is_prime_v1` below. Then I thought of trying a v2 by using the `any` built-in function, see `is_prime_v2` below. I was curious to know the time difference between v1 and v2, and with the code below I get the following output on my computer:

```
v1: 5.224290132522583
v2: 7.654775142669678
```

Which surprises me. I would have assumed that making use of `any` would take about the same time or even be faster. But here it's slower, a guess could be that it's due to the function call to `any` itself, but I'm unsure. Maybe someone with deeper Python knowledge could explain why?

```
from time import time
from math import sqrt


def is_prime_v1(n):
    if n < 3 or n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def is_prime_v2(n):
    if n < 3 or n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    return not any(n % i == 0 for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RANGE_SIZE = 2000000

    t = time()
    for i in range(RANGE_SIZE):
        is_prime_v1(i)
    print('v1:', time() - t)

    t = time()
    for i in range(RANGE_SIZE):
        is_prime_v2(i)
    print('v2:', time() - t)
```

Comment: generator expressions `n % i == 0 for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2)` slow things down. They are *essentially* equivalent to your regular loop but with overhead

Comment: Aha good point, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using solution 2, you have 2 for loops instead of one in your solution 1:

One in the any function (it needs to loop over the values you are giving it)

One as argument to the `any` function, which is equivalent to your original for loop.

Additionally, as @juanpa.arrivilaga pointed out, you are creating a generator object, which [creates additional overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382230/why-is-this-generator-expression-function-slower-than-the-loop-version).

Comment: "When using solution 2, you have 2 for loops instead of one" No? Why do you say that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well, one for loop _in_ the anyfunction itself, an the other for loop is the one from solution 1 in one line,

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `any` does use a loop, doesn't it ?